# How to fallback on an other classname if the first classname is not found in?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking for a way to create a fallback in my css selector. I would like to select `class2` only if no element with `class1` is found.

The closet thing I found was to use the "or" selector.

`.class1,.class2 {...}`

But obviously, it apply to `class2` even if `class1` is found.

Comment: CSS can't detect other classes...it can only syle based on the selector. A brief view of the HTML structure might help. Will these classes appear together on a element or on different elements? Equally, CSS can't select UP the DOM so *where* these elements are in the DOM will be *highly relevant*. Frankly JS is your best option here.

Comment: @Paulie_D On different elements. I will handle it with javascript finally. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to select `.class2` only if no element with `.class1` is
>   found.

Is `.class2` always a subsequent sibling ***or*** a descendant of `.class1`?

If so you can use a combination of:

- the `sibling selector` (`~`)
- the `descendant selector` ( )

Here's an example which uses `color: black` to indicate no selection and `color: red` to indicate selection:

```
.class1,
.class2 {
  color: red;
}

.class1 ~ .class2,
.class1 .class2 {
  color: black
}
```